# Multiple line Resultset into a hashMap

Tags: arraylist, hashmap

I have the following result set :

Name   Occurrence
Jack      2
Jill      1
Tom       3

I want to put this in HashMap? I was able to display only the one entry
Or is it best to use a ArrayList ?

Comment: What is the requirement ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Dictionary<string, int> dictionary =
        new Dictionary<string, int>();
    dictionary.Add("Jack ", 2);
    dictionary.Add("Jill ", 1);
    dictionary.Add("Tom ", 3);
```

Comment: What is the advantage of Dictionary to Map ?

Comment: strong data type..You Enter only those values which are belongs to specified data type..